# I have followed all the command to install ros melodic in Ubuntu bionic but stucked at setting up environment variables

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Run

```
echo "source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then after

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Showing

```
bash: /otp/ros/melodic/setup.bash: No such file or directory.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329877/i-have-followed-all-the-command-to-install-ros-melodic-in-ubuntu-bionic-but-stucked-at-setting-up-environment-variables./) by [1at7](https://answers.ros.org/users/44428/1at7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-08-02**:\

> /otp/ros...

is this a typo in your question or what you're actually seeing it should be `/opt/ros....` This could be causing your problem.

If you look at the contents of your .bashrc script you can check and fix the typo if that's the case

**Comment by [1at7](https://answers.ros.org/users/44428/1at7/) on 2019-08-02**:
i copy pasted from http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu
and it is like

```
echo "source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-03**:
Ok.

So what is the output of `ls -al /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`?

And the output of `lsb_release -a`?

And of `uname -a`?

**Comment by [1at7](https://answers.ros.org/users/44428/1at7/) on 2019-08-03**:
Output of
1st
`ls: cannot access '/opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash' : No such file or directory`
2nd
`No LSB modules are available.`
And for 3rd one.. my PC name, Ubuntu version, GNU/Linux

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-03**:
We need the verbatim, exact copy-paste of the `uname -a` output. You can change your PC name, but leave the rest.

As to the rest: it would appear that you haven't installed ROS.

**Comment by [1at7](https://answers.ros.org/users/44428/1at7/) on 2019-08-03**:
`unaame -a` output as

```
Linux *********  #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 27 07:28:31 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Comment by [1at7](https://answers.ros.org/users/44428/1at7/) on 2019-08-03**:
i even tried instaling LSB but it shows

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-03**:
Ah, that would appear to be your problem: it's likely that `apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full` didn't actually succeed. Didn't you get an error?

I'm pretty sure that the fact that `lsb_release` doesn't work is the cause of your problems.

What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`?

**Comment by [1at7](https://answers.ros.org/users/44428/1at7/) on 2019-08-03**:
it gives

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu


(lsb_release -sc) main
```

**Comment by [1at7](https://answers.ros.org/users/44428/1at7/) on 2019-08-03**:
output of trying install ros was w/o error when i run 1st time  but it gives this now

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-03**:\

> output of trying install ros was w/o error when i run 1st time

not saying you're lying, but without `ros-latest.list` setup correctly, it's impossible for `apt` to install anything.

**Comment by [sspanderkar@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/61120/sspanderkar@gmail.com/) on 2020-10-17**:
in my case its still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> it gives

> ```
> deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu
>
>
> (lsb_release -sc) main
> ```

The problem most likely is that `lsb_release` has not been setup/installed correctly, which causes the command given in the installation tutorials to produce incorrect output, leading to a malformed `ros-latest.list`, which then causes `apt` to fail downloading indices from the ROS package repositories, leading to `apt install` never succeeding to install ROS.

Steps to fix:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
sudo apt clean && sudo apt update
```

Pay special attention to the output of `apt update`. It should not report any errors or warnings.

Now you should be able to run `sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full` successfully, and a `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` should also succeed.

Note that we're avoiding the use of `lsb_release -sc` here by just specifying the `bionic` value (which is the codename of your Ubuntu distribution). If you'd like to fix `lsb_release` (and are sure `lsb_release -sc` doesn't actually output anything) you could try to do something like `sudo apt install --reinstall lsb-release lsb-core` and see if `lsb_release -sc` starts working.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [1at7](https://answers.ros.org/users/44428/1at7/) on 2019-08-03**:
thank god it worked finally.. i am really noob in linux  X)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-03**:
Does it now work?

---

> i am really noob in linux

If you're planning on using ROS, it would be good to get familiar with Linux (or just Ubuntu) a bit more. It will probably help make all of this less 'magic' and complicated.

**Comment by [1at7](https://answers.ros.org/users/44428/1at7/) on 2019-08-03**:
ya sure. btw thanks for support and quick response.
and it worked and now I have running ros core.
thanks again..